# What is the default MySQL JOIN behaviour, INNER or OUTER?

Tags: mysql, select, join

So I've been looking through the internet the last hour, reading and looking for the definitive answer to this simple question.

What is the default JOIN in MySQL?

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2
```

Is that the same as

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2

OR

SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
```

Also a related question, when you use "WHERE" clauses, is it the same as JOIN or INNER JOIN ?

Right now I'm thinking a stand-alone JOIN is identical to using commas and WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In MySQL writing `JOIN` unqualified implies `INNER JOIN`. In other words the `INNER` in `INNER JOIN` is optional. `INNER` and `CROSS` are synonyms in MySQL. For clarity I write `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` if I have a join condition and `CROSS JOIN` if I don't have a condition.

The allowed syntax for joins is described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

---

> Right now I'm thinking a stand-alone JOIN is nothing more than (identical to) using commas and WHERE clauses.

---

The effect is the same, but the history behind them is different. The comma syntax is from the ANSI-89 standard. However there are a number of problems with this syntax so in the ANSI-92 standard the JOIN keyword was introduced.

I would strongly recommend that you **always** use JOIN syntax rather than the comma.

- `T1 JOIN T2 ON ...` is more readable than `T1, T2 WHERE ...`.
- It is more maintainable because the table relationships and filters are clearly defined rather than mixed together.
- The JOIN syntax is easier to convert to OUTER JOIN than the comma syntax.
- Mixing the comma and JOIN syntax in the same statement can give curious errors due to the precedence rules.
- It is less likely to accidentally create a cartesian product when using the JOIN syntax due to a forgotten join clause, because the join clauses are written next to the joins and it is easy to see if one is missing.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for clarifying up this simple question for me :)  In the past I've always used commas+where clauses... but will be converting to using JOINs per your advice. Thanks

Comment: Hey Mark, what do you mean by mixes of JOIN and commas. Mix queries like this, SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c) ?

Comment: @Quang: This for example will fail: `SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON t1.x=t3.y WHERE t1.a = t2.b`

Answer (score 1):

These are all equivalent, and also equal to, `CROSS JOIN`.

There are some differences between using comma and `[INNER | CROSS] JOIN` syntax, which might be important when joining more tables. Pretty much all you need to know is described here in the [MySQL `JOIN` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Comment: ^--- answer to question is JOIN (standalone) basically is the same thing to INNER and comma+where clauses