# Join in Mysql doesn't produce the correct output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

Products table :

[image]

Family table :

[image]

I want to get all the `family_name` records of the products that have the same `family_code` as in the `family` table :

```
SELECT family_name 
FROM family
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.family_code=family.family_code;
```

But this code return all the `family_name` records .

Any idea where did I go wrong ?

Much appreciated

Comment: Why you use `LEFT JOIN`? I think it should be `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: can you mwntion what output you exactly want through dummy data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do an INNER JOIN, it will only show you records which are in both tables.  A LEFT JOIN will show all records from family regardless of whether they have a matching products table entry.

```
SELECT f.family_name 
FROM family f
INNER JOIN products p
ON f.family_code=p.family_code;
```

Comment: You needn't specify inner as the [default join type is an inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-standalone-inner-or).

Comment: A great observation!  I generally specify it for readability, especially in larger queries or with multiple joins (where the keyword helps it stand out).