# What is the default T-SQL JOIN behaviour, INNER or OUTER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question was asked for [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-standalone-inner-or) already, but for Transact-SQL, what is the default `JOIN` behaviour?

That is, is simply writing `JOIN` in a query synonymous with writing `INNER JOIN` (as is the case with MySQL), or something else, like perhaps `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: For those of you voting down this perfectly legitimate question because I answered it myself, please note that it is now encouraged to [answer your own questions if you can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect people aren't downvoting because you answered your own question, but because the question seems to have been asked before. The answer is also pretty easy to find in Microsoft's documentation (e.g. ["When no join type is specified, this is the default."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) in the documentation for FROM) which can lead to downvotes, even though [it perhaps shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN` behaviour.

To verify this, I ran the following code:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (x INT)
INSERT INTO @A
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2

DECLARE @B TABLE (x INT)
INSERT INTO @B
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3

SELECT 
    A.x AS 'A.x', 
    B.x AS 'B.x'
FROM @A A
JOIN @B B
    ON A.x = B.x
```

This produces just one row, consistent with `INNER JOIN` behaviour:

```
A.x  | B.x
-----+-----
2    | 2
```

Contrast this with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
...

SELECT 
    A.x AS 'A.x', 
    B.x AS 'B.x'
FROM @A A
FULL OUTER JOIN @B B
    ON A.x = B.x
```

This of course shows all three rows:

```
A.x  | B.x
-----+-----
1    | NULL
2    | 2
NULL | 3
```

Comment: In general, "trying it out" should not be used as a valid approach to conclude particular behavior is guaranteed or "the default" -- there are numerous `SET` options that can influence T-SQL behavior, for example, even though this happens to not be the case for `JOIN`. Your code is fine to illustrate the behavior, but is not authoritative. This is why I felt the need to post another answer, obvious as the question may be.

Comment: Also, the cynic in me would like to suggest that explicitly using `INNER JOIN` when that's the behaviour you want may be a nice idea if someone else needs to review your T-SQL script and perhaps doesn't remember this bit of the documentation.

Answer (score 23):

In T-SQL, `JOIN` without an explicit type is an `INNER JOIN`, as specified by [the documentation on the `FROM` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177634) (excerpt):

```
[ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
<table_source> ::=   
{  
    ...
    | <joined_table>
    ...   
}  

<joined_table> ::=   
{  
    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>
    ...   
}  

<join_type> ::=   
    [ { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } } [ <join_hint> ] ]  
    JOIN
```

> **INNER**
>
> Specifies all matching pairs of rows are returned. Discards
>   unmatched rows from both tables. When no join type is specified, this
>   is the default.

Answer (score 4):

For some MSDN reference.
To paraphrase, inner join is the default type of join.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx