# query from 5 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 5 tables as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE teacher (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE course(
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE student_course (
  student_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES student(id),
  course_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES course(id)
);
CREATE TABLE teacher_course (
  teacher_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES teacher(id),
  course_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES course(id)
);
```

and I want to query which student study what course with which teacher.

```
SELECT s.name, c.name, t.name
FROM student s
  JOIN student_course sc ON s.id = sc.student_id
  JOIN course c ON sc.course_id = c.id
  JOIN teacher_course tc ON c.id = tc.course.id
  JOIN teacher t ON tc.teacher_id = t.id
```

but the result is not what i intended. like 1 student studies one subject with 2 different teachers. It's not the input problem, cos i check and there's no duplicate input in both teacher_course, and student_course. So i think the problem is with my query. Can someone tell me where i went wrong?

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: can you post the output?

Comment: @AkankhaAhmed i just did. Please check it

Comment: Hey. Will it be complicated for you to provide data example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6479c9/1 to reproduce the problem? Query looks OK at a first glance.
Also, what version of MySQL you use?

Comment: Your results doesn't present all columns.

Comment: Might be shooting in the dark, but can you try this version of the query: 
'SELECT s.name, c.name, t.name
FROM student s, 
     student_course sc,
     course c,
     teacher_course tc,
     teacher t
WHERE s.id = sc.student_id
  AND sc.course_id = c.id
  AND c.id = tc.course_id
  AND tc.teacher_id = t.id'

Technically it should do the same, but... who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
 SELECT 
    s.name as Student_Name,
    c.name as Course_Name,
    t.name as Teacher_Name

From student s

inner join student_course sc on s.id = sc.student_id 
inner join course c on sc.course_id = c.id
inner join teacher_course tc on tc.course_id =c.id 
inner join teacher t on tc.course_id = t.id;
```

**result :**

[image]

Comment: thanks you! this works, turns out i only had to reverse the PK and FK. whether i left or inner join, i still get the same results. can u explain me little more about this. i thought it doesnt make any different whether u put the FK or PK first.

Comment: also, why the result is duplicated. Can u tell me how to not show duplicated results?

Comment: @AcousticMike there no duplicate value. yes, 2 students can take one course which can take by the same teacher.for example, 1st 2 column "oren" and "Nathaniel" takes the same course which is taken by Jacob Harteman.That why is at teacher and course_name are duplicate entry .

Comment: However, if you want to remove duplicate entry you can use "distinct "  after you select query.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql statement seems correct. I used LEFT JOINs though, because JOIN is by default an INNER JOIN (see [What is the default MySQL JOIN behaviour, INNER or OUTER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-behaviour-inner-or-outer)). But, based on your table syntaxes, I applied the sql statement both with JOINs and with LEFT JOINs and I received the same results. Anyway, my sql statement with LEFT JOINs is:

```
SELECT 
    s.*,
    c.*,
    t.*
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN student_course AS sc ON sc.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN course AS c ON c.id = sc.course_id
LEFT JOIN teacher_course AS tc ON tc.course_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN teacher AS t ON t.id = tc.teacher_id;
```

If the problem is as you said - "*like 1 student studies one subject with 2 different teachers*" - then the cause can only be the fact that you are assigning multiple `teacher_id`s to the same `course_id` in the table `teacher_courses`.

Note that the situation *one teacher can teach multiple courses* is a valid one. E.g. in `teacher_course` is allowed to have the same `teacher_id` for multiple `course_id`s.