# Selecting multiple table values with doubled joins

Tags: mysql, list, join, concatenation, group-concat

I have a query which selects values from different tables via JOIN. But I think I have a problem now, because one table needs to join in again with a different name, but somehow it doesn't work.

An example based on a social network strucutre:

Table "users":

```
+--------+-----------+
| userid | username  | 
+--------------------|
| 1      | userOne   | 
| 2      | userTwo   | 
| 3      | userThree | 
+--------+-----------+
```

Table "posts":

```
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
| postid | userid  | text                          |
+--------------------------------------------------|
| 102    | 1       | "Haha i'm User one"           |
| 103    | 1       | "And User one is the best"    |
| 104    | 3       | "I'm having fun with user two"|
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Table "usertags":

```
+--------+---------------+
| postid | tagged_userid | 
+------------------------|
| 104    | 2             | 
+--------+---------------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT posts.postid,
   posts.userid,
   posts.text, 
   users.username,
   IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT usertags.tagged_userid SEPARATOR ','), NULL) as 
taggedusers_id,
   IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT taggedusers.fullname SEPARATOR ','), NULL) as 
taggedusers_name, 
     FROM posts
JOIN users ON posts.userid = users.userid
LEFT JOIN usertags ON posts.postid = usertags.postid
LEFT JOIN users as taggedusers ON usertags.tagged_userid = users.userid
 GROUP BY posts.postid
 ORDER BY posts.postid DESC
```

And that's the result i get:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| postid | userid  | text                          | username           | taggedusers_id |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
| 102    | 1       | "Haha i'm User one"           | userOne            | NULL           |
| 103    | 1       | "And User one is the best"    | userOne            | NULL           |
| 104    | 3       | "I'm having fun with user two"| userThree          | 2
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

**The problem:**
The column 'taggedusers_name' shows up, but it always shows NULL. I want it to show the usernames of the users which are tagged. 
Like this, but in the whole, big output

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| taggeduser_id | taggeduser_name   | 
+-----------------------------------|
| 2             | userTwo           | 
| 2,3           | userTwo,userThree | 
| NULL          | NULL              | 
+---------------+-------------------+
```

So, how is this possible? Do I need to make a multiple SELECT statement? I tried that already, but I failed at this too :/
I'd be glad for help!

Comment: Your sample data doesnt match your desire output, also the schema arent complete you have missing columns used on the query.

Comment: Unrelated, what's the point of the `IFNULL(***, NULL)`? Basically, you're saying, if it's `NULL` set it to `NULL`. Seems redundant, unless there's a benefit I'm missing.

Comment: @KeithChason probably mean `IFNULL(***, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're referencing `users` again without the alias. Since `users` is already being implicitly `INNER JOIN` (see this question [What is the default MySQL JOIN behaviour, INNER or OUTER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-behaviour-inner-or-outer)) so the `taggedusers` table will have to meet the conditions that the author is the same as the tagged user ID.

```
SELECT posts.postid,
   posts.userid,
   posts.text, 
   users.username,
   IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT usertags.tagged_userid SEPARATOR ','), NULL) as 
taggedusers_id,
   IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT taggedusers.fullname SEPARATOR ','), NULL) as 
taggedusers_name, 
FROM 
    posts
JOIN 
    users 
    ON posts.userid = users.userid
LEFT JOIN 
    usertags 
    ON posts.postid = usertags.postid
LEFT JOIN 
    users as taggedusers 
    ON usertags.tagged_userid = taggedusers.userid -- this is (I assume) what you meant
    -- ON usertags.tagged_userid = users.userid -- this is your problem
GROUP BY 
    posts.postid
ORDER BY 
    posts.postid DESC
```

One way to avoid this is to always alias tables; in this case you could have aliased `users` as 'author' or something of the like.

The reason you didn't have the same problem with the distinct IDs is that it was on a table that was joined correctly.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me lots of hours realizing this