# How to do a cross join on specified column-values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following:

```
select * from main_genre
join (select 'SDBUY' UNION 'HDBUY') x
```

The results I'm trying to get are:

```
'Action', 'SDBUY'
'Action', 'HDBUY'
'Comedy', 'SDBUY',
'Comedy', 'HDBUY'
```

What would be the proper query from this in mysql?

Comment: Either `CROSS JOIN` or comma `,` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Also need to do `UNION SELECT...` and not just `UNION`.

Comment: @dnoeth what type of join does it do by default if you don't specify it in mysql?

Comment: In Standard SQL the keywords `inner`& `outer` are optional, `join` is an inner join, `left` & `right` are outer joins. Comma-delimited is older syntax, before they introduced the join keyword, where the join-condition is written as part of the WHERE and when it's ommited you get a `cross join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` and make sure each unioned statement has a `select` in it:

```
select * from main_genre
cross join (
  select 'SDBUY'
   union all
  select 'HDBUY'
) x
```

If the join type isn't specified in MySQL, it will use an `inner join`: [What is the default MySQL JOIN behaviour, INNER or OUTER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-behaviour-inner-or-outer/4418849#4418849).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
select g.genre, x.what
from (select 'Action' as genre union all select 'Comedy') g cross join
     (select 'SDBUY' as what union all select 'HDBUY') x;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Why do you do a `union all` here instead of a normal `union` ?

Comment: @David542 . . . A `union` is *not* normal.  It incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.  You should *always* use `union all`, unless you specifically want to incur that overhead.