# Joining the result of a select query with different distinct tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am simply querying a table

```
select label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
```

What I want to add to this query is the chance to JOIN the result of the Select with 3 different tables. Let's say the case of joining with 1 table only. The query would look like:

```
select label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock p
ON sig.label = p.Value
```

Now I want to join in the same way, at the same time, the result of the select with 2 more table. In my mind it would look like this:

```
select label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock p
ON sig.label = p.Value
JOIN ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock q
ON sig.proces = q.Value
JOIN ScreeningProducthAuthorizationLock s
ON sig.proces = s.Value
```

The result is not the expected one because the join works on the result of what comes before it, while I want it to be working from the Select statement. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the correct result is given by the following query:

```
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock p
ON sig.label = p.Value
union
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
INNER JOIN ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock q
ON sig.proces = q.Value
union
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
INNER JOIN ScreeningProductAuthorizationLock r
ON sig.product = r.Value
```

What I am looking is a way to avoid 3 Select queries and make it be only 1.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful here.  I suspect you might want to be using an `outer join` instead...

Comment: With MySQL default JOIN is an inner Join. Do you want a left join perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418776/what-is-the-default-mysql-join-behaviour-inner-or-outer https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @sgeddes just updated with an example!

Comment: You still have not clearly described how output is a function of input, and it is not clear what such a specification your example is an example of. Give a rule about when a row appears in the result based on what parts of it appear and/or don't appear in input tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
LEFT JOIN ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock p
ON sig.label = p.Value
LEFT JOIN ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock q
ON sig.proces = q.Value
LEFT JOIN ScreeningProducthAuthorizationLock s
ON sig.proces = s.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data and expected results, I believe you want to be using `union all`:

```
select s2.*
from Signalering s 
    join ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock s2 on s.label = s2.value
union all
select s2.*
from Signalering s 
    join ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock s2 on s.proces = s2.value
```

- [Demo Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j7kjDCVjr3fbVKTwveoZVK/0)

Comment: this one workks, but, is there a way to keep only one Select instead of repeating it all the time?